# Problem in jQuery.getJSON in rails 2.3.5

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, getjson

I want to use the getJSON() method for cross domain check i am using the following

`<script>
jQuery.getJSON("http://localhost:3003/home/unique_email/1?email=example@gmail.cmo&callback=result",
  {
    format: "jsonp"
  },
  function(result) {
   alert(result.text)
  });
  </script>`

in the controller

```
def unique_email
count = User.count(:all, :conditions => ['email = ?',params[:email]] )
result = Hash.new()

if count > 0
  result[:text] = "false"
else
 result[:text] = "true"
end
respond_to do |format|
  format.json {
  render :json => result
  }
end
```

end

I am getting alert in the same domain, which means that i am getting alert in my application but while putting the code out side the application means i am not getting any Error but the application action is called .. But i am not getting any response from the application.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks & regards,

Ramanavel Selvaraju.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Answer for this ,

Wen need to add the render_json method in application controller.

```
  private

    # render json, but also allow JSONP and handle that correctly
    def render_json(json, options={})
      callback, variable = params[:callback], params[:variable]
      logger.debug("render json or jsonp? Callback = #{callback}, Variable=#{variable}")
      response = begin
        if callback && variable
          "var #{variable} = #{json};\n#{callback}(#{variable});"
        elsif variable
          "var #{variable} = #{json}"
        elsif callback
          "#{callback}(#{json});"
        else
          json
        end
      end
      render({:content_type => :js, :text => response}.merge(options))
    end
```

So the we can get the dattype as jsonp in jQuery ajax.